# ImageViews inside GridView take up insane amount of space

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview

I am trying to fit in `ImageViews` inside a `GridView`. I have written a custom XML for the `ImageViews`, a custom Java class extending `ArrayAdapter` for the GridView.

Following is my Activity initializes my `GridView`

```
private GridView gridView;
private CustomGridViewImage customGridViewImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout2);

        init();
        handleClick();

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridViewImage);
```

Following is the **custom Adapter**

```
package in.juspay.ec.sdk.activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import in.juspay.ec.sdk.*;

/**
 * Created by stpl on 21/7/16.
 */
public class CustomGridViewImage extends ArrayAdapter<Integer>{

    private Context context;
    private Integer[] imageArray;

    public CustomGridViewImage(Context context, int resource, Integer[] imageArray)
    {
        super(context, resource, imageArray);
        this.context = context;
        this.imageArray = imageArray;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gridview_image, parent,false);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cell.findViewById(R.id.custom_gridview_imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Following in the **custom XML** for ImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/custom_gridview_imageView"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And lastly, the **XML for GridLayout**

```
    <GridView
       android:background="#e8bc9e"
       android:id="@+id/gridView"
       android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:numColumns="2"
       android:columnWidth="50dp"
       android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
       android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform">
   </GridView>
```

I'm trying to get something like this

[image: this]

But I end up getting this

[image]

As you can see, each grid cell takes up insane amount of space after the `ImageView`. So where am I going wrong?

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: For ImageView's ScaleType set it to centercrop. Or fix cell dimensions in adapter class programmatic

Answer (score 0):

Because you assign 50dp x 50dp for the ImageView's container (LinearLayout) in custom layout. And tell GridView to make it 2 columns. So your images are small and rest of the area is filled with the background color.
You can delete the LinearLayout section in custom layout and put only Image View  with width: match_parent, height: match_parent. Or change the LinearLayout's width & height as "match_parent".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

Replace your  ***custom XML for ImageView*** with just this (removing the LinearLayout)

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/custom_gridview_imageView"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

From then on, adjust the ImageView's size with padding, this will adjust the ImageView to its container.